# Binary and additional files

Tags: go, directory, package

I'm trying to package my go application binary which is accessible by a web interface running on localhost:8080 so that when downloaded it's able to find the JS(front-end) files in the folder where the file is ran but i can't seem to make it work.

I've been doing something like this :

```
  pwd, err := os.Getwd()
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
      os.Exit(1)
  }
```

Then trying to use the working directory of the binary to access the files inside it but that doesn't seem to work.

The binary is located at :

/Users/admin/Desktop/testappfolder

but when i run the program with just :

```
pwd, err := os.Getwd()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
fmt.Println(pwd)
```

I end up getting `/Users/admin` as the working directory instead.

I wondering :

Where i'm going wrong ?
Is this has something to do with the Gopath ? 
Am i going at it the right way regarding distributing the app as a "zip" and having file path setup directly inside my program relative to the working directory ? or is it that logic that's wrong ?

Comment: take a look here: https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.Getwd` is going to correspond to where you *start* your binary from not where the binary is located.

To make for a more robust solution I would pass in the location of the files directory using a [flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) or using a config value.